# Unix Shell Sed Pattern March with Space

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I want to `grep` the data after the "*DA*":

```
BSSID:Broadcast DA:Broadcast SA:da:a1:19:dd:aa:92 (oui Unknown) Probe Request
```

the output should be

```
Broadcast
```

And the data

```
BSSID:d8:49:2f:74:dc:cf (oui Unknown) DA:d8:49:2f:74:dc:cf (oui Unknown) SA:d8:49:2f:74:dc:cf (oui Unknown) Probe Request
```

Should be

```
d8:49:2f:74:dc:cf
```

I use the command

```
echo " -90dB signal [bit 29] BSSID:Broadcast DA:Broadcast SA:f4:9f:f3:d6:68:bc (oui Unknown) Probe Request (PremiumOutletsJP) [1.0 2.0 5.5 11.0 Mbit]" | 
sed -rn 's/.*DA:(.*)[:space:]/\1/p'
#it is echo "$DATA"|sed -rn 's/.*DA:(.*)[:space:]/\1/p'
```

But the output is:

```
 Broadcast SA:f4:9f:f3:d6:68:bc (oui Unknown) Probe Request (PremiumOutletJP) [1.0 2.0 5.5 11.0 Mbit]
```

Or I try the command:

```
echo "$DATA" | sed -rn 's/ DA:(.*) /\1/p'
```

Those are wrong.
Could anyone guide me to fix the error and tell me how to learn pattern match of regular-expression ? thank you.

Comment: Is this a string or a line of text from a file?

Answer (score 0):

`grep` solution: Using look around.

```
echo "$DATA"|grep -oP 'DA:\K[^ ]+'
Broadcast
echo "$DATA"|grep -oP 'BSSID:\K[^ ]+'
d8:49:2f:74:dc:cf
```

Using `sed`:

```
echo "$DATA"| sed -r 's/BSSID:([^ ]+).*/\1/g'
d8:49:2f:74:dc:cf

echo "$DATA"| sed -r 's/.*DA:([^ ]+).*/\1/g'
Broadcast
```

Here required string is captured inside `(` and `)` and later called using `\1`. `([^ ]+)` means capture anything till space character is seen.

Comment: But there is a space after the DA:XXXXX string, why I could not set a pattern to match it ?

Comment: Sorry I do know your point: "DA:d8:49:2f:74:dc:cf (oui Unknown)", there is a space between f and (, why the extract would not be successful ?

Comment: you also need `(oui Unknown)` in output ?

Comment: @GaigerChen so does it provide you correct output or you expect something else ?

Comment: I do not know why the pattern matching would be failure for "DA:d8:49:2f:74:dc:cf (" case..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148575/discussion-between-ps-and-gaiger-chen).